# When cursor is idle and moved pulse effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want it so when you move the cursor after not moving it for a few seconds a pulse effect plays around it.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body,
  a:hover {
    cursor: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png), progress !important;
  }
</style>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" _blank " title=" ">
  <img src=" " border="0 " alt=" " style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; " />
</a>
```

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: You may want to start with fixing your html first. Anchor tag is formatted wrong and quotations are all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to take a look to two plugins:

- [jquery.pulse](http://jsoverson.github.io/jquery.pulse.js/)
- [jquery-idletimer](https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer)

And so an example could be:

```js
$(function () {
  $(document.body).idleTimer({
    timeout: 1000,
    idle: true,
    events: 'mousemove'
  });
  $(document.body).on("active.idleTimer", function (event, elem, obj, triggerevent) {
    var ele = $(triggerevent.target);
    ele.pulse({backgroundColor: 'red'}, {pulses: 3}
             );
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer/master/dist/idle-timer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jsoverson/jquery.pulse.js/master/jquery.pulse.min.js"></script>


<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="">aaaaa</a>
<img        src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" border="0" alt=""
        style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;"/>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```